# Printing contents of an ArrayList/Array and Deep Copy of film Array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class MainTest
{
    public static void main (String [] args){

        ArrayList<Actor> a = new ArrayList<Actor>();

        a.add(new Actor("Jack Nicholson","Miami",74));
        a.add(new Actor("Violante Placido","Bologna",38));

        Film [] filmList= new Film [3];
        filmList[0] = new Film ("Wolf");
        filmList[1] = new Film ("As Good As It Gets");
        filmList[2] = new Film ("One Flew Over The Cuckoo's Nest ");

        a.get(0).setFilm(filmList);

        filmList[0] = new Film ("The American");
        filmList[1] = new Film ("Ghost Rider Spirit of Vengeance");
        filmList[2] = new Film ("Barah Aanan");

        a.get(1).setFilm(filmList);





    }


}
```

I am nearly there with this project except two parts I am struggling with,the two below,do you need a loop to display the details? Just printing the array doesn't seem to work also I have been reading about Deep copy today but always struggle to apply things to my own code. Any pointers welcome thanks.

**Using the Actor array/Arraylist print the actor’s details on the first line followed by the details of his/her films on the following lines. 
Note :- each Actor has to have his/her own collection of Films – this is known as a deep copy.  If the actor shares his copy of films with another actor it is a shallow copy.**

Comment: So you're problem is that you dont understand what a deep copy is? You just create a new array, copy the values over and use the new array. This differs from a shallow copy, which affects the original when changing it

Comment: First, the classes Actor and Film are provided, so so we can only guess what you're code is doing. Second, could you try retesting the question you are asking. It just isn't clear at all. Your second to the last paragraph says the issue are the 'the two below' but the next paragraph doesn't have any questions/issues. Just some obscure (thought not necessarily baseless) concerns about deep copies and data sharing.

If we were looking at your Actor and Film class, this might be completely clear, but without them it certainly isn't.

Comment: The Actor and Film classes get and set the Actor's name age and address and the 3 films they were in I now need the print the Actor's details on the first line using they Array/Arraylist and print the details of their 3 films on the following lines. Then make a deep copy of the actors film array.

Comment: Not sure where the deep copy is coming in. To print the films, get a reference to ArrayList from the Actor object, the just do a loop over it.